# How to extend workbook horizontally without clicking right arrow ("→") button a "thousand" times?

Tags: microsoft-excel, office365, scrolling, scrollbar

The problem relates to the horizontal scroll bar and why it won't scroll to areas to the right / horizontally where there is no data. This is frustrating especially as old versions of Excel (which I no longer have access too) never had this issue. I often have the need for putting data not only vertically but also horizontally in the Excel file.

So, I find that the only way of "efficiently" doing this is hammering the "→" button right next to the horizontal scroll bar and when I have enough space I write "dd" / any text in a random cell furthest to the right. This is to prevent the "newly created empty space" of being removed as I move left in the workbook to copy different sets of data. Think of it like caching up a large portion of empty space but filling it gradually with data instead of having a "wall" set up by Excel that ends right next to where my data also ends. Here is a picture showing what I want to happen

[image: region with no data]

To use horizontal scroll bar across empty data space, where the gap to the right between the horizontal scroll bar and the right arrow ("→") button is essentially scroll-able area of region with no data (if you disregard the "dd" text I had to put there to force Excel to do this).

To compare, this is what I don't want:

[image: scroll bar at the end]

where empty space I have manually scrolled to now being removed automatically as I move back to the left to my data (i.e. to copy and to paste in the empty area).

Ideally I would like to be able to use the horizontal scrolling bar such that when I move it to the right "boundary" it will open up more space to the right as earlier Excel versions, instead of just stopping as it does now.

I know I can copy first, click "→" many times and then paste the extra data. But still the issue resides. Essentially I want some "breathing" room of empty space between where I have data and where I might or might not put more data.

Anyone have any clue how to fix this, to make the horizontal scroll bar work as it should?

Comment: If you know the specific cell you want to navigate to, you could also just enter its address in the address input left of the value input.

Comment: note that "extend" means "select" in editors so it'll be confusing to use that word. For example "extend right" means select the character/cell/word/whatever... in Word, Excel, Notepad++...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never seen that behavior from Excel. AFAIK it has always been like that since at least Excel 97

But you can easily scroll one page horizontally by right clicking on the scrollbar > *Page Left/Right*, or use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Page Up/Down</kbd>. So you can just move the scroll bar to the very right end with the mouse (or by right clicking the scroll bar > *Right Edge*) and then press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Page Down</kbd>

[image: Excel scroll bar]

[Keyboard shortcuts in Excel for Windows](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Keyboard-shortcuts-in-Excel-for-Windows-1798d9d5-842a-42b8-9c99-9b7213f0040f)

Comment: Thanks a bunch ! :D Both methods work fine. I also really liked the alt + page up/down method.

Comment: I do notice however that when I go back (doing alt+page down) Excel removes the newly created space. So seems I will have to write "dd" or some text regardless after doing alt+page down. But at least its faster than the right arrow button

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>right arrow</kbd> in a new sheet to immediately hop to the 16,384<sup>th</sup> column and putting some text there will work as an alternative to repeatedly clicking on the right arrow next to the horizontal scroll bar.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/839473)

Comment: In fact, it does answer the question. Q: "How do I create a state of affairs where the horizontal scroll bar will scroll through many empty, unused cells without having to hit the right arrow many times to get to a place where I can add data?" A: "Instead of repeatedly hitting the right arrow next to the scroll bar, press ctrl+right arrow." Question answered. I'll look forward to your upvote

Comment: I edited out the extraneous commentary

Comment: There's a bit of assumption happening between "I want to scroll beyond the filled area of a spreadsheet" and "I want to go the furthest logical cell". Granted, OPs hyperbole about clicking thousands of times does make one think they may be trying to get to the end, but the rest of the question doesn't make draw the same assumptions. So, you may be right, you may not be.

Comment: Thanks for the effort both of you. Yes, I did meant to scroll beyond the filled area and not to the furthest end. So, though it works its a little too much. I should have just refrained from using the "thousand times" mention

Comment: Definitely some assumptions were made. Regardless I provided the fewest keystrokes to achieve the OP's goal as stated. OP apparently wanted something slightly different. That's fine, but my answer is clearly a valid answer.